# How to create multiple endpoints through powershell for New AzureML WebServices

Tags: powershell, azure, machine-learning, azure-powershell, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a ML WebService on portal.azure.com. I wish to create multiple endpoints programmitically for this webservice using Powershell. 
However all the cmdlets available (Add-AmlWebServiceEndpoint) involve using the Old or Classic WebServices.

Is there anyway to achieve this for New Azure ML WebServices

Answer (score 0):

What version of PowerShell are you using, and have you imported the Azure-RM module? [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-4.3.1).

You can see updated documentation for all the cmdlets that can be used with ARM-based Azure Machine Learning web services [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.machinelearning/?view=azurermps-4.3.1).

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.14393.1715

Yeah, I have imported the Azure-RM Module and I'm able to execute cmdlets.

My doubt is as to how to go about creating endpoints for AzureML Webservices(new and not classic)